# Pandas:drop_duplicates() based on condition in python

Tags: python, pandas

Having below data set:

```
data_input:

    A     B
1  C13D  C07H
2  C07H  C13D
3  B42C  B65H
4  B65H  B42C
5  A45B  A47C
```

i.e. row 1 and row 2 in `data_input` are same,I just want to keep one,so drop row 2.

Want the Output as below:

```
data_output:

    A     B
1  C13D  C07H
2  B42C  B65H
3  A45B  A47C
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can create a third column `'C'` based on `'A'` and `'B'` and use it to find duplicates as such:

```
df['C'] = df['A'] + df['B']
df['C'] = df['C'].apply(lambda x: ''.join(sorted(x)))
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset='C')[['A', 'B']]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `duplicated` and `np.sort`

```
In [1279]: df[~df.apply(np.sort, axis=1).duplicated()]
Out[1279]:
      A     B
1  C13D  C07H
3  B42C  B65H
5  A45B  A47C
```

---

Details

```
In [1281]: df.apply(np.sort, axis=1)
Out[1281]:
      A     B
1  C07H  C13D
2  C07H  C13D
3  B42C  B65H
4  B42C  B65H
5  A45B  A47C

In [1282]: df.apply(np.sort, axis=1).duplicated()
Out[1282]:
1    False
2     True
3    False
4     True
5    False
dtype: bool
```